Vim syntax - nextgroup confusion
I'm using Vim 8.2.2121 on Ubuntu 22.04 with vim-gtk.
I'm trying to follow this guide:
https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Creating_your_own_syntax_files
I have created the syntax and ftdetect cel.vim files. I'm seeing the correct filetype detected; and I'm getting highlighting; and I can make changes to the syntax file and see those reflected. But I'm not seeing the behaviour that the tutorial says I should.
I have the following rules:
syntax match celNumber '\d\+'
syntax keyword celBlockCmd RA Dec Mass SpectralType nextgroup=celNumber skipwhite
syntax keyword celBlockCmd Distance AbsMag nextgroup=celNumber skipwhite

let b:current_syntax = "cel"

highlight link         celBlockCmd     Statement
highlight link         celNumber       Constant

I'm also including the .cst file here. It's the one given in the tutorial.
600000 "My Star"
{
  RA 24.40648
  Dec -9.404052
  SpectralType "Q"
  Mass 1.09
  AbsMag 1.29
  Distance 124.729260
}

When I open the cst file, the celBlockCmds are highlighted as Statements (good). But 'Dec' and 'SpectralType' are also highlighted as Statements (bad). Shouldn't nextgroup mean that the celBlockCmd highlighting only happens for keywords that are followed by the celNumber regex?
Anyone know why this might be?

"Shouldn't nextgroup mean that the celBlockCmd highlighting only happens for keywords that are followed by the celNumber regex?" - no, according to :help nextgroup: If the "nextgroup" argument is given, the mentioned syntax groups will be tried for a match, after the match or region ends.

Yes - but I'm finding this difficult to interpret. Does this mean that using nextgroup in a syntax keyword group isn't allowed?

I'd simply understand that as a hint as in "after celBlockCmd, prefer to match celNumber". I could be mistaken, of course. The link you provide does little to specify expected behavior. So all we're doing is guessing...

You can think that nextgroup raises the match priority. Basically, that's all it does, except it can also override "contains" related rules. But that's not important in your case, as you don't have any region here.

Ok - this question was based on an assumption of behaviour on my part - it turns out that vim syntax matching doesn't work that way. Thanks for this.
